# Session Management in different domains on Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, session, azure

I have implmented Sessions State mangment using using this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_buildingappswithcacheservice_topic3.aspx)

It works fine as far as I am in same domain but when I change domain it failed.
can you tell me how can I share session between domain.

On

http://simpletix.cloudapp.net/Default.aspx

I am setting up session thats why you can read `<h1>Default.aspx</h1>` on this page.

Now If I go http://simpletix.cloudapp.net/Contact.aspx
I can again see that heading because it is set by default page already.

Now I have another domain which is pointing to same site but diffrent domain.When I open after opening link above I am hoping that contact page on racreg.com will also show me sample session value `<h1>Default.aspx</h1>` but it is not showing

http://test.racereg.com/Contact.aspx

can you please tell me what workaround to achive session between domain

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080017/how-to-share-session-among-multiple-domains-on-single-asp-net-website Not possible over different top level domains. Even with your shared session server, that is not the purpose of it in the first place.

Comment: what about SSO? can we implment sso for sharing sesion id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As f0x points out, you cannot share a cookie over these top level domains. This means you'll need to revert to cookieless sessions (the session ID will be stored in the url). In order to do this you'll need to modify the web.config (`<sessionState cookieless="true" />`).

Comment: True, but session state only supports cookies or cookieless: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx