# Write cookies from subdomain and read from another subdomain without changing web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a simple question. I have two different projects like

```
http://login.mydomain.com
```

and

```
http://test.mydomain.com
```

. As it's name suggests, I login from login project and response redirect to test project.

I am able to create cookie for login.mydomain.com but I can not read it from test.mydoamin.com.
My question is can I create cookie from **login.mydomain.com** to **www.mydomain.com** and read it from **test.mydomain.com** as if I am reading it from **www.mydomain.com**.

**This is how I create my cookies.**

```
Response.Cookies["UserValidForMyDomain"].Value = myvalue;
Response.Cookies["UserValidForMyDomain"].Expires = dtExpireDate;
```

**and how I read them.**

```
string myValue = Request.Cookies["UserValidForMyDomain"].Value;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can create a wildcard cookie for the domain of `.mydomain.com` which will allow any subdomain to read/write it.

Answer (score 2):

**TO WRITE**

```
HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie("key", "value");
hc.Domain = ".mydomain.com";
hc.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(hc);
```

**TO READ**

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["key"].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

In `php` this will do [session_set_cookie_params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

In `asp` and equivalent, these stackoverflow thread might be usefull

[How to share session among Multiple Domains on single asp.net website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080017/how-to-share-session-among-multiple-domains-on-single-asp-net-website)

[How can you keep a session across multiple subdomains in c# mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424307/how-can-you-keep-a-session-across-multiple-subdomains-in-c-sharp-mvc)