# How to send cookies from account.domain.com to app.domain.com?

Tags: c#, node.js, firebase, authentication, cookies

How to send cookies from **account.domain.com** to **app.domain.com**?

I am working on an authentication. I want to send cookies from **account.domain.com** to **app.domain.com**. The problem is, I can send cookies in the response header but the browser does not set the cookie. I can see in the network tab, cookies present in the response header.

I want to use these cookies across all sub-domains i.e ***.domain.com**

cookie sent from **account.domain.com**

```
 var cookie = new HttpCookie("key", "value");

     cookie.Domain = "domain.com";
     cookie.HttpOnly = true;
     cookie.Secure = true;
     cookie.SameSite = System.Web.SameSiteMode.None;
     cookie.Path = "/";

 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

 return Ok();
```

on the client side, I use javascript(Axios) to send them.

```
await axios("https://app.domain.com/endpoint", {withCredentials: true});

await axios("https://api.domain.com/endpoint", {withCredentials: true});
```

I want to send these cookies with every request so I can authenticate.

Comment: Configure the cookie's path, domain etc (I think if you use domain.com as the path, it should work). Anyway, please post snippet of your code and someone will be able to help faster.

Comment: Do you set the Domain property of cookie before returning it to the browser?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  updated my question these are my configuration.  the domain is a placeholder.

Comment: Are you adding cookie to the response by doing `Response.Cookies.Add`? How are you trying to send cookies from browser to the other domain? It will be helpful if you share code which sends cookies to the browser and the code which sends cookies from browser to the other application and how the other application tries to read the cookie from the request?

Comment: @Sekhar i update my quesion.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya quesion updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write cookies from subdomain and read from another subdomain without changing web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831605/write-cookies-from-subdomain-and-read-from-another-subdomain-without-changing-we)

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831605/write-cookies-from-subdomain-and-read-from-another-subdomain-without-changing-we I think you need a leading "." on the domain (.e.g `cookie.Domain = ".domain.com"`